# Как в SQLALCHEMY задать в модели виртуальный расчетный столбец для MS SQL?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, sqlalchemy

необходимо описать в модели SQLAlchemy 2.0 столбец [date_c], который на чистом SQL задается след образом. Он становится Computed, Persisted

```
CREATE TABLE table (
    year INTEGER NULL, 
    month INTEGER NULL, 
    day INTEGER NULL, 
    hour INTEGER NULL, 
    minute INTEGER NULL, 
    [date_с]  AS (datetimefromparts([year],[month],[day],[hour],[minute],(0),(0))) PERSISTED)
```

Comment: Вот здесь что-то похожее обсуждается https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326290/sqlalchemy-calculated-column

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/defaults.html#computed-ddl